# DD-WRT as VPN Server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, dd-wrt

I been reading several articles here on superusers.com itself but still confused about DD-WRT and VPN

***Questions***

1. Does DD-WRT Router itself acts as a VPN Server
2. Does VPN Clients will be directly to get authentication from DD-WRT Router itself?
3. Are there any other services, or configuration required on any internal machines to make DD-WRT router as VPN Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) yes
2) I'm not sure what you mean by this
3) once the VPN server is established you'll need to configure each client to go through the VPN (I usually go with openvpn as its simple to use)

Are you sure you're wanting your router to act as a VPN server and not a VPN client (I.e, route all traffic through router through a VPN tunnel to an external VPN provider)

Comment: 2. I mean if dd-wrt itslef is my VPN Server, does it authentication the VPN Client coming from internet if yes what kind of client those can be

Comment: i have few windows server so instead of opening RDP ports i think if i can have VPN Server on my router then all i need to do is open VPN Ports instead of RDP Ports,

Comment: Then yes, you can set it up as a VPN server and all that any connected clients will require is whatever you choose to make them require. I use openVPN server on my DDWRT router so that I just need to install an openVPN client on my clients and import the generated .ovpn file

Comment: can you please share settings if possible or if you have a followed a public tutorial please share the link. i am trying out PPTP but open to openVPN or anything

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/64433/how-to-install-and-configure-openvpn-on-your-dd-wrt-router/